# AngularJS Controller is not working with ngRoute in IntelliJ (Web server issue?)

Tags: html, angularjs, intellij-idea, controller, ngroute

I am making a basic app using ngRoute. The routing is working, but my scope element inside my controller is not being shown in the html.

```
<p>{{ message }}</p>    <!-- Nothing shows -->
<p>{{ message }}X</p>   <!-- 'X' shows -->
```

Angular, Route, App, and Registration scripts are referenced in the main html.

```
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <main class="cf" ng-view></main>
  </div>
</body>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            contoller: 'RegistrationController'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
            contoller: 'RegistrationController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });

}]);
```

registration.js

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = "Welcome to my App!";

}]);
```

login.html

```
<section class="card login">
  <form name="myform"
    novalidate>

    <div class="textintro">
      <h1>Hi there!</h1>
      <p>Log-in to access the awesomeness!</p>
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>

    <fieldset>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
    <p>or <a href="#/register">register</a></p>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Everything looks right to me. If you throw a `console.log("RegistrationController");` right above your `$scope.message = ...` line does it show up in the console?

Comment: @Lex Nothing outputs. Somehow the controller is not being connected the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo:

```
contoller: 'RegistrationController'
```

should be:

```
controller: 'RegistrationController'
```

Comment: Ugh! It's the little things! Thanks Lex!